# Rake test failing in test environment only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rake

I am running "rake test" over my Rails 3.0.7 (Ruby 1.8.7) project via the command line.

My rails app is a fairly basic out-the-box app, as I am still learning. E.g. my Gemfile is:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '3.0.7'
gem 'sqlite3'
```

When I do this without specifying the environment, it works. I presume this is hitting development, as when I try and point at the development environment, it still works ! Also when I run "rake test:units" or "rake test:functionals" these work without error too.

However, when I run against the test environment, the unit tests fail to run ? I have tried this both from Rubymine IDE and command line with the same results.

The trace outputs look as follows - firstly plain "rake test" :

```
C:\Users\Ben\dev\railstest>rake test --trace
(in C:/Users/Ben/dev/railstest)
** Invoke test (first_time)
** Execute test
** Invoke test:units (first_time)
** Invoke test:prepare (first_time)
** Invoke db:test:prepare (first_time)
** Invoke db:abort_if_pending_migrations (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute db:abort_if_pending_migrations
** Execute db:test:prepare
** Invoke db:test:load (first_time)
** Invoke db:test:purge (first_time)
** Invoke environment
** Execute db:test:purge
** Execute db:test:load
** Invoke db:schema:load (first_time)
** Invoke environment
** Execute db:schema:load
** Execute test:prepare
** Execute test:units
Loaded suite C:/dev/lang/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake/rake_test_loader Started
.......................
Finished in 2.821289 seconds.

23 tests, 24 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors
** Invoke test:functionals (first_time)
** Invoke test:prepare
** Execute test:functionals
Loaded suite C:/dev/lang/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake/rake_test_loader Started
.............
Finished in 3.34668 seconds.

13 tests, 25 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors
** Invoke test:integration (first_time)
** Invoke test:prepare
** Execute test:integration
```

And now the failing run against the test environment

```
C:\Users\Ben\dev\railstest>rake environment RAILS_ENV=test test --trace
(in C:/Users/Ben/dev/railstest)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke test (first_time)
** Execute test
** Invoke test:units (first_time)
** Invoke test:prepare (first_time)
** Invoke db:test:prepare (first_time)
** Invoke db:abort_if_pending_migrations (first_time)
** Invoke environment
** Execute db:abort_if_pending_migrations
** Execute db:test:prepare
** Invoke db:test:load (first_time)
** Invoke db:test:purge (first_time)
** Invoke environment
** Execute db:test:purge
** Invoke test:functionals (first_time)
** Invoke test:prepare
** Execute test:functionals
Loaded suite C:/dev/lang/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake/rake_test_loader Started
.............
Finished in 3.328125 seconds.

13 tests, 25 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors
** Invoke test:integration (first_time)
** Invoke test:prepare
** Execute test:integration
Errors running test:units!
```

There is no more text in the error message, and no further indication what the errors actually are. I have re-run `db:schema:load` on both sqlite3 environments and `db:seed` to populate a few database tables too, although the test data is loaded via fixtures normally.

I figure the problem here is trying to run unit tests against the test environment, but I can't understand why ?

Comment: How about when you run `rake test:units`? I don't think `rake test` with any option is going to run it under any environment other than test under normal conditions. (Write a test that prints Rails.env, run `RAILS_ENV=development rake test` and see what prints out.)

Comment: Ah good point, forgot to say the individual rake test:units and test:functionals commands work without error. Edited above to declare that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `rake test` all unit, functional, and integration tests are run in the test environment. From what you've shown, the tests are working exactly as expected. You don't need to explicitly tell rake to use the test environment - that is assumed.

Comment: Well, I guess I'm happy to not specify the environment, if that's causing the issue; but still puzzled why explicitly targeting the (default) test environment then causes the command to fail ?

Comment: When you run "rake test" you start by blowing away the test environment's database structure and replacing it with the current environment's structure (development by default). When you run "rake RAILS_ENV=test test" you are telling it to replace the test db structure with the test db structure, which is a scenario that hasn't been tested (I can't think of a use case).

Comment: Ah, I understand better now. Was happy to accept what I did was a bit foolish, but wanted to understand exactly how it's foolish :)